# Porque comparação usando javascript não funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**O que eu quero fazer:**

Algoritmo que gera logs de alteração dos campos no front-end.

**Problema:**

Certo trecho do código eu comparo o valor antigo com o novo valor:

```
            if( value =! anterior ){
                elemento.val( value ).attr( 'data-anterior', anterior ).toggleClass('log_inativo log');
            }else{
                elemento.toggleClass('log log_inativo');
            }
```

Porem, independente dos valores ele está caindo no if e depois no else infinitamente.

**Código**

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Grava o valor anterior do campo
    $( "input, select" ).focus(function(){            

        //Grava o atual valor em um atributo atributo
        var anterior = $(this.tagName + "[name="+ this.name +"][data-anterior]");           

        //Se o atributo não existe, ele é criado
        if(!anterior.length){
            $(this).attr('data-anterior', this.value);
        }
    }).change(function(){           

        //Define as variaveis
        var value = this.value;
        var anterior = $(this.tagName + "[name="+ this.name +"][data-anterior]").attr('data-anterior');
        var name = this.name;
        var elemento = $( "input[name=log_" + name + "]" );         

        console.log("value:", value, "anterior:", anterior);
        //Verifica se já não existe um elemento de log
        if( elemento.length ){

            //Verifica se o novo valor alterado não é o valor antigo
            if( value !== anterior ){
                elemento.val( value ).attr( 'data-anterior', anterior ).toggleClass('log_inativo log');
            }else{
                //Então remove
                elemento.toggleClass('log log_inativo');
            }
        }else{ //Se não existe ele cria
            $( ".formInner" ).append( "<input type = 'hidden' class = 'log' name = 'log_" + name + "' value = '" + value + "' data-anterior = '" + anterior + "'>" );
        }           

    })})
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class = "formInner">
    <input type ="text" name = 'item1' value ="teste 01">
    <select name ='item2'>
        <option selected> banana </option>
        <option> banana 2 </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/anndreyy/gzdg3f5o/8/

**Obervação**

Para fazer a verificação na linha 20, do js, tem console.log do valor inserido e do valor anterior. 
[image: teste 01]
Note que classe mudou para log_inativo, mas o valor digitado é diferente do valor anterior
[image: teste 02]

O que será que estou fazendo de errado? Valeus.

Comment: `=!` deveria ser `!=`. Será só isso?

Comment: @bfavaretto pelo que analisei o problema é apenas este. kk

Comment: Realmente não tinha me tocado a respeito disso. que burro eu sou =)
Porem, o problema continua.

Comment: Você está dizendo que o valor é igual ao oposto do anterior (value =! anterior)

Comment: E mesmo trocando, quando vc faz o toggle, vc inverte a condição. Fazendo com que ele nunca saiba qual é a forma que você quer permanecer.

Comment: Ivan, obrigado. Esse era realmente esse o problema.

Comment: Outra coisa que você pode fazer, é trocar: `.attr( 'data-anterior', anterior )` por `.data('anterior', anterior)`, quando você usa data-elemento, a palavra data, já é uma referência do elemento, que conterá atributos.

Comment: Valeu, vou fazer isso! obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O colega [Ivan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26539/ivan-ferrer), resolveu o meu problema, que no caso era a função toggle. A operação de comparação estava funcionando perfeitamente, mas como a função toggle inverte as variáveis, independente da ordem que as classe inseridas dentro dele foi colocada, então sempre ia inverter independente de qual o valor das variáveis value e anterior.

Curioso que eu coloquei essa função só para testar, não ia usar ela de fato. 
Substitui pela função remove, já que no começo do algoritmo e verifico se existe um elemento hidden com o nome do elemento, se não tiver eu crio um novo.

```
//Verifica se o novo valor alterado não é o valor antigo
            if( value !== anterior ){
                elemento.val( value ).attr( 'data-anterior', anterior );
            }else{
                //Então remove
                elemento.remove();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A condição seria valores diferentes `!==`

**Exemplo:**

```js
var value = "a";
var anterior = "b";

if (value !== anterior) {
  document.write('diferente');
} else {
  document.write('igual');
}
```